# Cannot enable Pod Security Admission controller on Minikube

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, podsecuritypolicy

I'm trying to enable the new PSA controller with Minikube but no luck (neither with Kind).

Here is the command I'm using to start minikube: `minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.25.3 --feature-gates=PodSecurity=true --extra-config=apiserver.enable-admission-plugins=PodSecurity`

This is not really documented properly but I found that there is both a feature-gate for PSA and the admission controller plugin. Even enabling both seems to have no effect.

To make sure I'm not missing something, here is how I'm trying to test it:
Namespace configuration:

````
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  labels:
    pod-security.kubernetes.io/enforce: restricted
  name: psa```

Super unsecure Deployment:
```apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment-unsecure
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 0
        runAsGroup: 0
        fsGroup: 0
      volumes:
        - name: etcvol
          hostPath:
            path: "/etc"
            type: Directory
      containers:
        - name: nginx
          image: nginx:1.14.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
          securityContext:
            allowPrivilegeEscalation: true
            privileged: true
            capabilities:
              add: ["NET_ADMIN", "SYS_TIME"]```


When I try to create this deployment in the `psa` namespace it goes through without a hitch.
````

Answer (score 0):

Ok I realized this was my misunderstanding of how PSA should work. The PSA controller doesn't check higher level resources like Deployments it seems. So the Deployment gets created just fine but then it can't create Pods because those would be violating the policies.

No configuration is needed at all for minikube (or Kind) at all (no feature gate or admission plugins configuration) if running Kubernetes 1.25.

```
kubectl run --image=nginx nginx
Error from server (Forbidden): pods "nginx" is forbidden: violates PodSecurity "restricted:latest": allowPrivilegeEscalation != false (container "nginx" must set securityContext.allowPrivilegeEscalation=false), unrestricted capabilities (container "nginx" must set securityContext.capabilities.drop=["ALL"]), runAsNonRoot != true (pod or container "nginx" must set securityContext.runAsNonRoot=true), seccompProfile (pod or container "nginx" must set securityContext.seccompProfile.type to "RuntimeDefault" or "Localhost")
```